# JAVA/JUNIT : I am trying to simulate a User Choice Input in my unit test; What shall I use without prompting any system out?

Tags: testing, input

I have the a Game interface and Logic works perfectly but the input od the user is causing lot of trouble and i have tried System.in Buffere Reader ..... with no lucl at all

the Game is the dominoes

and this my output

---

*YARD*

---

(5-1)

MY HAND

(6-0)(5-4)(5-2)(6-3)(4-1)(3-1)(5-3)

AVAILABLE

(5-4)(5-2)(4-1)(3-1)(5-3)

Options:
 {1}  {2}  {3}  {4}  {5}

Please Select one bone from above options : "in here i will input my integer"

as you can see the user is pushed to make mistakes and he/she only need to digit an integer;

how do i bypass this step in JUNIT after i set up my table,hand and available moves?

Answer (score 0):

Move the entering part to a method and stub/mock it in your test cases

Comment: Is there any other way avoiding mocking or mockito or even stub sub tests? i am confused JUNIT should be so easy to use and set upt... why when come on simple input has to srtuggle so much?

Comment: i know what you meant know;

Comment: When you say move the entering part into a stub/mock and then recall it in the test itself? Can you show an example? it would make me understand perfectly